# git + ssh > remote empty, tree and non-bare

Tags: git, github, ssh

I try to use git on loacl and to deploy on production.
I use bracket and the git plugin also.

**The ideal situation**

**[local]**
local/my/working/folder

**[remote 1]**
github

**[remote 2]**
remote2/my/server/folder/theme

The configuration with github works well.
With my server i get some difficulties. I use ssh to push and to connect to the server.

**What i did on remote 2**

```
$ mkdir git/theme
$ cd git/theme
$ git init
```

**What i did on local**
git remote add origin ssh://user@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:yy/home/user/git/theme

At the beginning, i get some error:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

So i solve the problem with the commande into /home/user/git/theme :

```
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

But i notice, the .git folder was update on the push but none of my files of local/my/working/folder

I remove every think on remote 2 and start a new remote.

Finally i get these configurations:

**[local]**

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "github"]
        url = git@github.com:me/theme.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = github
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://user@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:yy/home/user/git/theme/theme.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**[remote 2]**

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
```

When i use

```
$ git push origin master
```

.git is update but none of the file are push.

As i begin, i tried a lot of thing but all the tuto i test don't work perfectly. The communication between my local and remote 2 works well, it's a good start.

First i am confusing about bare and non-bare repository.

Why when i push to remote 2 it doesn't push the file in my folder?
Why on local branch master is connect to remote 1?
Why when i push to remote 2, it push to the branch origin/master and not master?

Thank you in advance for any help.
jB

Answer (score 0):

> Why when i push to remote 2 it doesn't push the file in my folder?

By push to remote repository, you don't push the files, but only the index. Bare repository does not contain the files (or track of them). When you try to clone the repository from somewhere else, you will see that you will get all the files.

Comment: As i understand i have to clone the repository before any push... But how clone my local repository? I can't access it from my server (remote 2)?

Comment: No. I didn't tell anything like that. If you want to create new mirror, create new bare repo (`git init --bare`) and, add it as a [remote] and just push into that (maybe `-force` push).

Comment: Sorry for my confusion: when i push to github my local folder, i notice files and .git are update. Why it doesn't work like that with my remote on my server. I have make a test: clone github remote on my server. On local, when i push to my server, i get a message **everything is up to date**. When i make a change on a local file, i get an error when i push to my server. I don't understand at all. Otherwise i think about scp my local folder but until now i got an error **Could not resolve hostname ssh**.

Comment: on github you don't see the actual files, don't you? You see only web interface.

Comment: sorry i edit my post. Yes i see change into the web site.

Comment: I make an exact copy using scp (thank you). For this remote, i get this error when i push after a new commit on local _remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master        
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository        ...
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match        ...    
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to        
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into        
remote: etc..._